# nstextfield задание stringvalue

Tags: swift3

Доброго времени суток.Столкнулся вроде с проблемой при задании значения stringValue для Объекта NStextField
Я новичок в swift, строго не судите.

В общем я создал форму(ControllerView)  кинул на него textlable  и кнопку.

Далее код:

```
lass ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var etc_balance: NSTextField!

@IBAction func loadbal(_ sender: NSButton) {



   guard let  url = URL(string: "https://mysite.io/data.json") else {return }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, err) in

        if let data = data{
        print(data)
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)

                if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
                    if let number = dictionary["data"] as? Double {
                 print(number)
                       self.etc_balance.stringValue = String(number)
                    }else{
                        print("NoKeyfounds!")
                    }
                }

            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()
```

Проблема в строке

```
 self.etc_balance.stringValue = String(number)
```

Изменения текста не происходит. Если эту же строку прописать в самом начале класса то текст меняется.  Мне нужно вывести значение переменной numbers
Подскажите в чем причина.

Answer (score 0):

Отбой. Разобрался. Я предполагал что проблема кроется в протоке.
Как я понял все изменения в UI  нужно оборачивать  DispatchQueue.main.async